# JPA: How to map relationship in MSA

Tags: jpa, orm, microservices

User Entity

```
@Entity
class User{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CASCADETPYE.ALL)
   private List<Product> products;
}
```

Product Entity

```
@Entity
class Product{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

I just created the simple entities.(just omitted constructors etc)
say this is separated project for MSA.
How do I mapping the relationship between two entities since I can't import the each entity?

Answer (score 0):

you will create one dummy class mean without entity with same variable's and call another service using Fein client or rest client create user with out entity and save it.